# how to log in to a linux server?

Tags: java, linux

I have a linux server
what i have

1 : hostname

2 : port no

3 : username

4 : password

now how can i log in to this linux server and execute some commands

till now what i found is

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("host -t a " + domain);
    p.waitFor();

    BufferedReader reader = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";           
    while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
```

but there is no login procedure , this might be pretty dumb to ask this but I have no idea what i am missing,
please help

Comment: You need to establish some kind of SSH (secure shell) through which you can execute your commands.  Also `p.waitFor` is blocking, it will wait for the process to terminate, so unless you have separate threads dealing with I/O, then not much is going to happen.  Also `ProcessBuilder` is a better choice when you want to execute an external command...

Comment: @MadProgrammer : any link for reference ??

Comment: [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/) popup

Comment: Check this out: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: @MadProgrammer : thanks , let me try this

Answer (score 1):

Hussain, what you need here is a SSH API like J2ssh : http://www.sshtools.com/archives/category/j2ssh-maverick

Or if you are ready to go that far you can use java sockets and the underneath connection protocol's raw commands to write commands to socket out stream and read response from in stream.

- j2ssh is licensed but deserves the cost, you can find similar free/opensource APIs as mentioned by MadProgrammer.